# Read big JSON payload all at once with Reactor Netty client, and not in chunks for keep-alive long lived persistent connection

Tags: netty, project-reactor, keep-alive, reactor-netty, persistent-connection

To describe the use case I am trying to solve/implement, we integrate with the 3rd party service, and this service sends a continuous stream of data (JSON) over HTTP/1.1 long-living/persistent connection (which can stay open up to the 2-3 hours, which is another question, on how the connection pool will behave in this case, as all connections over the HTTP client only to this host). But the problem I have at the moment, I connect and subscribe to the data like the following

```
 client
            .get()
            .uri("/")
            .responseContent()
            .asString()
             // .aggregate() // 1
            .subscribe(content -> {
                  logger.info("Running content on thread {}: {}",
                        Thread.currentThread().getName(), content);
            });
```

For small JSON it works fine, for the large JSON, `content` contains the part of the full JSON, so by itself, it is not the valid JSON or complete data. Is it possible to always get the whole data no matter the size in one chunk (is there a way to set a large `ByteBuf` size to fit any JSON payload into one response?) or if not, how you can wait and combine multiple parts of the same JSON response into the complete valid JSON?

To give an example, what I mean (I reduce the size of the JSON payload in the example, but just to demonstrate the idea), saying the server sends the following JSON:

```
{"id":1, data: [1, 2, 3]}
```

And on the client-side, I get the data/response in 3 chunks, i.e.

- chunk 1: `{"id:1", dat`
- chunk 2: `a: [1, 2`
- chunk 3: `,3]}`

(and then after chunk 3 I see `READ COMPLETE` in the log, see below).

If I enable `aggregate()` nothing is printed at all, as I understand it will wait for the connection to be closed, but as it is a persistent long-living connection this will not work.

The interesting part is that if enable `.wiretap(true)` on the client, it prints in the logs `READ COMPLETE` when large JSON has been split into multiple `ByteBuf`-s only when the full JSON content is consumed (not after every individual ByteBuf part), which might mean that the client knows when the processing of the single data response from the server is over.

I have found there is `.httpResponseDecoder` as it looked like the client limits the chunk to 16kb, although I extended it to 2mb, i.e. `.httpResponseDecoder(spec -> spec.maxChunkSize(2 * 1024 * 1024))`, but still don't get the whole JSON as a single data chunk, and still see the limit of 16kb max per chunk.

Any idea how I can achieve this or where to look into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Gitter https://gitter.im/reactor/reactor-netty Violeta Georgieva suggested to give a try and use `JsonObjectDecoder`, added the following to the client:

```
client.doOnConnected(connection -> connection.addHandler(new JsonObjectDecoder()))
```

And now gets the proper JSON on each subscription processing.

Comment: You additionally can look into https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/blob/c1c2858c2529c0154da88aa88c896631b48a00e3/reactor-netty-core/src/test/java/reactor/netty/tcp/TcpServerTests.java#L631

Comment: Additionally, if you know that your data in the stream is delimited by some kind of separators you can use `DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder`.

Comment: Or even `LineBasedFrameDecoder` (if you know your content is separated by the line-endings \n or \r\n), which will be faster than `DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder` as per the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You could reduce the flux and concat the data to get the whole response body.

```
    Mono<byte[]> responses = client
        .baseUrl(baseUrl)
        .get()
        .uri(uri)
        .response(((response, byteBufFlux) -> {
            // Check status code here if you want
            return byteBufFlux;
        }))
        .map(Utils::readByteBuf) // It reads ByteBuf to a byte array
        .reduce(this::concatByteArray);
        
  private byte[] concatByteArray(byte[] dataPart1, byte[] dataPart2) {
    byte[] data = new byte[dataPart1.length + dataPart2.length];
    System.arraycopy(dataPart1, 0, data, 0, dataPart1.length);
    System.arraycopy(dataPart2, 0, data, dataPart1.length, dataPart2.length);
    return data;
  }
```

And you could optimise it to use ByteBuf instead of byte array.